# jquery ui - undefined is not a function on dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm at my wit's end here.  I have a link on my page that is designed to load the contents of a PartialView into a `<div>` on my page as a draggable modal.  The Javascript code to load the content into a div works, but my callback to create the modal fails with the following error:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
> jquery-1.8.2.min.js:19p.fn.extend.add 
> jquery-1.8.2.min.js:19p.fn.extend.addBack 
> jquery-1.8.2.min.js:19a.widget._getHandle 
> jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js:23a.widget._mouseCapture 
> jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js:23a.widget._mouseDown 
> jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js:23(anonymous function) 
> jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js:23p.event.dispatch 
> jquery-1.8.2.min.js:19g.handle.h jquery-1.8.2.min.js:19
```

Code from HTML head as defined in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <link href="/Content/siteV2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

</head>
```

Javascript code to execute that resides on my ViewPresentationSchedule.cshtml page, which is returned as a `View`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAddForm() {
        $('#AddPresenterForm').load('@Url.Action("AddPresenterForm", "Pod", new { podId = pod.PodId })',
            function () {
                showform();
            }
        );
    }

    //fades in our help popup and makes it draggable but not resizable
    function showform() {
        var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var popupHeight = $('#AddPresenterForm').height();
        var popupWidth = $('#AddPresenterForm').width();
        $('#AddPresenterForm').css('position', 'absolute');
        $('#AddPresenterForm').css('top', windowHeight / 2 - popupHeight / 2);
        $('#AddPresenterForm').css('left', windowWidth / 2 - popupWidth / 2);
        $('#AddPresenterForm').fadeIn('slow',
        function () {
            $('#AddPresenterForm').draggable();
            $('#AddPresenterForm').css('display', 'block');
        });
    }

</script>
```

Div on ViewPresentationSchedule.cshtml, which is returned as a `View`:

```
<div id="AddPresenterForm">

</div>
```

Link to make all the magic happen:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showAddForm()">Add Presenter</a>
```

Any ideas what may be happening?  I suspect that jQuery UI is not loading/initializing properly as I have .datepicker() commands on other pages that don't work as well.

Comment: Which line of the `showform()` function is throwing the error?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It actually processes successfully.  It's when I click on the DIV to drag it that I encounter the error.

Comment: Check your browser's debugger console for network errors. In my experience, that error means a script did not download correctly, or a script was executed in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, there was something wrong with my jQuery files.  I deleted them and retrieved them from a CDN and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it has to do with where you are initializing `draggable()`. You could probably initialize the `draggable()` prior to loading the content. I assume `#AddPresenterForm` is hidden until the Add Presenter button is clicked, in which case it wouldn't be a problem if it is already draggable by the time it becomes visible.

If that doesn't seem to work you could use jQuery UI Modal Dialogue box which could make what you are doing a lot easier.

Here is a link to an example that seems to match what you are trying to do: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form